# Continuity for making a call on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

This is more sort of a "can we do it" question.
I am building an iPad app which has a phone icon. I show and hide the phone icon based on the device capability of making a call through telephony framework and canOpenURL check. I was wondering if I can utilize the continuity to make a call? I have my iPhone and iPad synced through continuity. Can I somehow check this continuity and then enable the user to make a call from my iPad app through continuity via iPhone? Is that doable?